# I want to know the type of effect usedin this type of animation.?

Tags: animation, blender

What is this style called where the object drops in comes close to the camera and flys back to a position in the background.[please refer to 0:29 time in which the pillows first drops in and than goes back to a certain position in the background](https://youtu.be/Z483hHrCudI?si=ma9g6x9UulViw4Bk)

Comment: Hi. Blender animation questions should be asked on Blender Stack Exchange, and video editing in general is off-topic here.  Please read our help page on [what questions you can ask here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Video makers have now and then inserted drop-ins. It became easy about 20 years ago when hobbyists started to be able to afford a video editing program. One could for ex. separate an object just from the first frame of a video clip, remove its background and add it to a new track as a static image. An elementary  keyframe animation of the static image made it look like it slides into the scene for ex. by dropping from the sky. The original clip starts just when the animated static image ends. Before hobby videos the effect was, of course, used in movies, which had the needed methods available earlier. Today one makes it all in a phone or low cost computer (assuming he has at first shot the needed video material and installed a decent video editing application).

I'm sure the furniture ad do not use such elementary methods. There 3D models of the items are programmed to do just the showed movements in the 3D scene.

If the old school version is interesting, see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifdtKW9lggo Making the wanted pillow motion in this way is possible, but needs surely some work and good quality images which fit the wanted result. Fortunately there's no need to make the pillows to fly. It's only a keyframe animation.